# How to use an external command in Vim to modify the selection

Tags: vim, stdout, stdin

Something I've found useful in other editors is the ability to:

- take the selected text
- run an external command and pass the selection to its `stdin`
- take the external commands `stdout` and replace the current selection with it.

*This way you can write useful text tools which operate on the selection using any language that can do basic io.*

How can this be done with vim?

(Directly in the command line, or via a key binding?)

Answer (score 3):

`:'<,'>!command`

`'<,'>` represents the (linewise) visual selection and is automatically inserted when you hit `:` and have something selected.

Example:

If you select a line containing:

`print("Hello!")`

and run the Vim command:

`:'<,'>!python`

the text will be replaced with `Hello!`.

If you want to set this to a key-binding (F5 to evaluate for example)

`vnoremap <F5> :!python<cr>`

Comment: Vim documentation: [`!` in Visual mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#v_!). See also [`!` in Normal mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#!), which filters text within a motion, and the [`:read!`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#:read!) command, which inserts the output of an external command.

Comment: This is probably really obvious but I've searched for some time and cant find how to hook this up to a key binding: eg: _F5 to evaluate Python selection_ `map <F5> :'<,'>!python<CR>`, Gives me `E492: Not an editor command: '<,'>'<,'>!python`, any hints on how to do this?

Comment: If you use that command in visual mode, hitting `:` will automatically populate the ex command line with `'<,'>`. Your mapping will also add a `'<,'>`. That's why you're getting duplicates. I'd recommend a mapping like: `vnoremap <F5> :!python<cr>`.

Comment: This takes the entire line, not just the selected text. Is there a way to get only the selected part of the line?

Comment: No. Not without writing some custom Vimscript. See `:h range`. Ranges are linewise only.